# Tabris Xcode Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: xcode, linker, mach-o, tabris

I tried to get the Tabris iOS-Client working. 
I imported everything in Xcode, registered my Phone as a Developer-Phone on Apple's page. Downloaded my provisioning profile and created a new Tabris project in Xcode.

The client-app runs perfect in the simulator, but when I try to run it on my iPhone I get the     following error:

```
ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/Shared/Tabris/Frameworks/Tabris.framework/Tabris for architecture armv7s
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I hope somebody can help me with this. :)

Thanks in advance,
Toby

Comment: Thanks for your report.
We'll try to reproduce and provide you with a fix.
Which iPhone do you have?

Comment: The tip from John helped me to fix it. It is an IPhone 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like something very similar to an issue we had before Tabris 1.0 which was resolved by setting the 'Valid Architectures' in the XCode project to 'armv7' only i.e. remove 'armv7s' from the list.

I cannot remember the reasoning, but it was something we found with a Google search, tried it, and it resolved our issue.

We now have a different iOS issue with Tabris 1.0, but that will be another thread.

Best regards, John

Comment: You're right! This fixed the problem.
I also had to check "build active architectures only - NO" and then it worked.